# Python program to put proper punctuations in a given string

Tags: python, text, nltk, text-mining, punctuation

I want to put proper punctuation marks in a given paragraph having many punctuationless sentences.

E.g:

- input: *hey how are you can you come today*
- output: *hey, how are you? can you come today?*

I just want to split the sentences to isolate the question part and the statement part. Basically, I need to put only "." and "?" at appropriate places.

Is there any protocol to do the same.
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: This is possible, but you would have to write your own algorithm to do it.

Comment: @ScottMcC I couldn't come up with a fruitful algorithm. I just tried with simple grammar structure using POS tags but it's not giving good results

Comment: @BenBotvinick any suggestion , what should be the approach?

Comment: Well what I would do is first split the string into pieces and look for specific parts of it. Let me write an answer to show you.

Comment: @BenBotvinick I tokenized the paragraph using nltk and using POS tags, I created a grammar structure to guess the proper mark, but there could be millions of different types of sentences. So, i couldn't come up  with a algo which works precisely in all the cases.

Comment: Your task is impossible in general. It may be possible to come up with an algorithm that works for specific examples, but not one that works with any possible text.  The reason is simple: There are many sentences that if you change the position of punctuation, you get a different result. Example:

Go play outside
1. Go play outside!
2. Go! Play outside!
3. Go play, outside!

Comment: @tonypdmtr I just want to split the sentences to isolate the question part and the statement part. Basically, I need to put only "." and "?" at appropriate places. And yeah I did it. I'm getting positive results

Comment: @Mohit I doubt it. Another question mark only example: 1. How many are you ok? 2. How many? Are you ok?

Answer (score 2):

The task of adding proper punctuations in a given string is called "[punctuation restoration](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=punctuation+restoration&btnG=)" in the research community. (no idea why the question got so many downvotes by the way, punctuation restoration is a valid research area).

Python programs for punctuation restoration:

- https://github.com/geyang/deep-auto-punctuation # Pytorch, 2017, char-level, no license.
- https://github.com/ottokart/punctuator2 # Theano, 2016, word-level, MIT license.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple algorithm that will check for the word 'hey' and add a comma after it:

```
def format(string):
    # get list split by spaces
    parsed_string = string.split(' ')
    i = 0
    for word in parsed_string:
        # check if word is 'hey'
        if word == 'hey':
            # add a comma
            parsed_string[i] = 'hey,'
        i += 1
    return ' '.join(parsed_string)

sentence = 'hey how are you'
print(format(sentence))
```

Output:

```
hey, how are you
```

Comment: this is a very specific solution. As I said in my comment that I need a generalized algorithm which will work in all the cases

Comment: imagine you have a paragraph with all the punctuations removed and you have to put back the punctutaion marks at appropriate places

Comment: I tokenized the paragraph using nltk and using POS tags, I created a grammar structure to guess the proper mark, but there could be millions of different types of sentences. So, i couldn't come up with a algo which works precisely in all the cases